# Removing Gnome GUI and Booting From CLI

Tags: console, startup

I'm running an ARM version of Ubuntu provided by Linaro. I'm not 100% sure on current version as I'm re-installing using the manufacturing tools (I want to say its Linaro 11.10). However, I was wondering if anyone could help me with an issue?

I did a `sudo apt-get remove gnome*`, to get rid of all the GNOME packages since I do not want a GUI. I restarted the system and I did not get a CLI. The screen was just black.

Is there a way to get to CLI or where/how would I change the files to boot to CLI?

Comment: I would simply leave these things installed and switch the default runlevel to a non GUI one.

Comment: The reason to not have it installed is to save limit the number of unnecessary packages in the memory.  Either way I am still having issues of changing the runlevel and having it boot directly to CLI.

Comment: Removing them only saves on disk space, if you're running in a GUI-less runlevel then none of the GNOME packages would be loaded consuming any RAM. I'd take a look at this SU Q&A: http://superuser.com/questions/310978/starting-ubuntu-without-the-gui

Comment: I have taken a look at a few guides.  I am not sure of my bootloader but I do know I am running System V.  So I believe this has different runlevel meanings.  I have tried numerous times of changing them to boot directly to CLI and not run the GUI with no success.  I will take a look at your link to further my knowledge tho.

Comment: What kind of console do you have, hardware-wise? Do you want to keep a GUI (an X server) available (to be reached upon explicit demand with `startx`), or do you want to remove X altogether?

Comment: I am planning on making a server that you can SSH into and have apache on it so that I could be able to allow video to be transmitted through an embedded device.  So no need for the X at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to another console by using Ctrl + Alt + F1/F2/F3/... to have access to a text-console. If that doesn't work, restart the system with single as kernel parameter.

As soon as you have a console, you can login to the system and stop your display manager:
Check which display manager is running with `ps aux|grep dm` or look for gdm or other *dm in /etc/init.d/ and check if they are started with `/etc/init.d/gdm status`

stop the currently running display manager with:

```
/etc/init.d/gdm stop
```

Now, disable the display manager for the next boot:

```
sudo vi /etc/init/gdm.conf
```

change

```
stop on runlevel [016]
```

to

```
stop on runlevel [0126]
```

Comment: I am running lightdm.  I had to use 'service lightdm stop' to stop it from running.  I changed the runlevel to as you said and upon reboot it seems to still boot into the GUI.  Any other ideas?

Comment: You dit edit sudo vi /etc/init/lightdm.conf instead of sudo vi /etc/init/gdm.conf, right?

Uninstalling lightdm would also work since you seem to want to remove gnome completely.

Comment: Yes I edited lightdm.conf, I want to say that I may not have the right graphics drivers for when the GUI is loaded.  A screen black screen with a blinking cursor comes up if I change the runlevel to a 1.  But if i just ad 2 to the stop on runlevel it still loads the GUI